# Validating path in cpp: Cannot able to remove special characters with ASCII code

Tags: c++, validation, path

```
for(i=0,j=0; (((temp[i] >= 0x2F) && (temp[i] <= 0X39)) || 
              ((temp[i] >= 0x40) && (temp[i] <= 0x5A)) || 
              ((temp[i] >= 0x61) && (temp[i] <= 0x7A))) ;i++) {
         printf("\n%c valid\n\n",temp[i]);
         msg[j++] = temp[i];
}
msg[j] = '\0';
```

In this snippet, i couldnt able to ignore (dot), space and new line characters, kindly help with your inputs.

console:

Input:"  \n \n ,,,,/storage/   sdcard0/  ... fusionlogs"

final output: (empty)

Comment: `isalnum(temp[i])` would be much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably you want  :

```
for(i=0,j=0; temp[i] != 0 ;i++) {
  if (((temp[i] >= 0x2F) && (temp[i] <= 0X39)) || 
      ((temp[i] >= 0x40) && (temp[i] <= 0x5A)) || 
      ((temp[i] >= 0x61) && (temp[i] <= 0x7A))) {
    printf("\n%c valid\n\n",temp[i]);
    msg[j++] = temp[i];
  }
}
msg[j] = '\0';
```

else the *for* stops on the first character not compatible with the test, and because your input starts by a space the *for* stops immediately.

Additional remark, do not use ascii code, use char directly (e.g. '.'), and you also have functions like *isspace* etc to not be linked to a given code.

So if you want to still use the same test do :

```
  if (((temp[i] >= '/') && (temp[i] <= '9')) || 
      ((temp[i] >= '@') && (temp[i] <= 'Z')) || 
      ((temp[i] >= 'a') && (temp[i] <= 'z'))) {
```

as you can see this is more readable, but this still makes assumptions on the characters codes ordering because you suppose '0' comes just after '/' etc.

If your goal is to only get the alphanumeric characters more / and @ do that :

```
  if (isalnum(temp[i]) || (temp[i] == '/') || (temp[i] == '@')) {
```

Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

char * filter(const char * temp)
{
  char * msg = new char[strlen(temp)];
  size_t i, j;

  for (i=0,j=0; temp[i] != 0 ;i++) {
    if (isalnum(temp[i]) || (temp[i] == '/') || (temp[i] == '@')) {
      printf("\n%c valid\n\n",temp[i]);
      msg[j++] = temp[i];
    }
  }
  msg[j] = '\0';

  return msg;
}

int main()
{
  char * s = filter(" \n \n ,,,,/storage/ sdcard0/ ... fusionlogs");

  puts(s);
  delete [] s;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra p.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out

/ valid


s valid


t valid


o valid


r valid


a valid


g valid


e valid


/ valid


s valid


d valid


c valid


a valid


r valid


d valid


0 valid


/ valid


f valid


u valid


s valid


i valid


o valid


n valid


l valid


o valid


g valid


s valid

/storage/sdcard0/fusionlogs
```

---

But we are in C++ so an other possibility is to use `std::string`, I did not used above because your `msg[j] = '\0';` clearly indicates you use C array.

Example :

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string filter(const std::string & temp)
{
  std::string msg;

  for (auto c : temp) {
    if (isalnum(c) || (c == '/') || (c == '@')) {
      std::cout << c << " valid" << std::endl; // it is useless to produce 3 newlines
      msg.push_back(c);
    }
  }

  return msg;
}

int main()
{
  std::string s = filter(" \n \n ,,,,/storage/ sdcard0/ ... fusionlogs");

  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra p.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
/ valid
s valid
t valid
o valid
r valid
a valid
g valid
e valid
/ valid
s valid
d valid
c valid
a valid
r valid
d valid
0 valid
/ valid
f valid
u valid
s valid
i valid
o valid
n valid
l valid
o valid
g valid
s valid
/storage/sdcard0/fusionlogs
```

Note it is also possible to modify a copy of the initial string (so not using a const reference of it) removing the non expected characters rather than to create an other string

Comment: Thanks Bruno, using if { } works fine, but please help me understand why the same conditions was not working when used inside for() loop.
Also, please clarify why I shouldnt use ASCII code, because if the Path provided has some spaces or other special characters inbetween, those also I need to remove,
for eg. "/sto  rage/  sd   \n card/" => this also I need to correct it as "/storage/sdcard/"

Comment: @RameshAravindM Your original code exits before even entering the loop. The `condition` in `for (init; condition; inc)` **terminates** the loop if it is not met. So in your case, if the first character is not alphanumeric, the loop **ends**.

Comment: Regarding the answer, I would recommend putting the test into a function. Nobody wants `if` or `for` arguments that span three lines.

Comment: @MaxLanghof the three lines have to disappear to be replaced by a simple form using _isxxx_ function ;-)

Comment: That is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot @bruno that was a great helping gesture I admire! Got understood clearly now.